# Is there a single Retransmission Timer for each sent TCP packet?

Tags: networking, tcp

I have a question concerning the Retransmission Timer of TCP. I have read a lot of articles, blog entries and other stuff about TCP Congestion Control and of course I have came across the Retransmission Timer.
Maybe it is a stupid question but sometimes it is mentioned that for each sent segment a timer is started and at other places it is said that the timer is reset for each sent segment.
So is there a single Retransmission Timer for each sent segment, so that there are as many timers as sent segments, or is there only one Retransmission Timer?

Comment: TCP segments (not packets) are not individually acknowledged, so a retransmission timer for each segment doesn't make sense.

Comment: Cumulative acknowledgements is one the reasons why the statement of a Retransmission Timer for each sent segment has confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Below lines come from "TCPIP Illustrated, volume 1", so seems only one timer exists, the new one replaces the old one.

> Once a sending TCP has established its RTO based upon measurements of the time-varying values of effective RTT, whenever it sends a segment it ensures that a retransmission timer is set appropriately. When setting a retransmission timer, the sequence number of the so-called timed segment is recorded, and if an ACK is received in time, the retransmission timer is canceled. The next time the sender emits a packet with data in it, a new retransmission timer is set, the old one is canceled, and the new sequence number is recorded. The sending TCP therefore continuously sets and cancels one retransmission timer per connection; if no data is ever lost, no retransmission timer ever expires

Answer (score -1):

There is generally (individual implementations could of course do something non-typical) a single retransmission timer and it is reset when new data has been acknowledged by the other side.  The time from when the data was sent and when it is acknowledged is used to update the RTT (round-trip-time).

Remember that TCP operates based on sequence numbers and not packets, which is how cumulative acknowledgements work.  An implementation doesn't even need to record how the stream was segmented.